# Creating website programmatically

Tags: magento2

I'm using magento 2.3. I'm trying to create a website through a custom command. Here's my code

```
$website = $this->websiteFactory->create();
$website->setName("foo")->setCode("foobar");
$website->save();
var_dump("expression");
```

This gives an error - Validation Failed. In Save.php line 59.

However, it does create the website.

If I remove $website->save(), "expression" is displayed.

Stack trace:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Validation\ValidationException): Validation Failed
#0 vendor/magento/module-inventory/Model/StockRepository.php(67): Magento\Inventory\Model\Stock\Command\Save->execute(Object(Magento\Inventory\Model\Stock))
#1 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Inventory\Model\StockRepository->save(Object(Magento\Inventory\Model\Stock))
#2 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Inventory\Model\StockRepository\Interceptor->___callParent('save', Array)
#3 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Inventory\Model\StockRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Inventory\Model\Stock))
#4 generated/code/Magento/Inventory/Model/StockRepository/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Inventory\Model\StockRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, Array)
#5 vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Plugin/Store/Model/ResourceModel/Website/AssignWebsiteToDefaultStockPlugin.php(100): Magento\Inventory\Model\StockRepository\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Inventory\Model\Stock))
#6 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\InventorySales\Plugin\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website\AssignWebsiteToDefaultStockPlugin->afterSave(Object(Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Store\Model\Website\Interceptor))
#7 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Store\Model\Website\Interceptor))
#8 generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/ResourceModel/Website/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', Array, NULL)
#9 app/code/Sample/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/HelloWorld/Index.php(27): Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website\Interceptor->save(Object(Magento\Store\Model\Website\Interceptor))
#10 generated/code/Sample/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/HelloWorld/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Sample\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\HelloWorld\Index->execute()
#11 vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(108): Sample\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\HelloWorld\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#12 vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(231): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Sample\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\HelloWorld\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#15 vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Sample\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\HelloWorld\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Sample\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\HelloWorld\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Sample\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\HelloWorld\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 generated/code/Sample/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/HelloWorld/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Sample\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\HelloWorld\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#19 vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(159): Sample\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\HelloWorld\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Sample\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\HelloWorld\Index\Interceptor))
#21 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#23 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#25 vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#27 vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#28 pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#29 {main}
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to create a website programmatically?

Comment: try setting a sort order and a default group id. probably 0 for group id `->setSortOrder(1)->setDefaultGroupId(0)`

Comment: Still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try :
    $website = $this->websiteFactory->create();

```
$website->setCode('foobar');
$website->setName('foo Name');
$website->setDefaultGroupId(1);
$this->websiteResourceModel->save($website);
```

where `$this->websiteResourceModel` is `Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website`

Comment: It isn't working. I have updated the question with the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I am having exactly the same issue - I have handled it by catching the exception and ignoring it if the website actually saved (because it does).

```
/**
 * @namespace   Namespace
 * @module      WebConfig
 * @brief       Module for Installation Scripts for Websites, Stores, Groups, etc.
 */

namespace Namespace\WebConfig\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\GroupFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Group;
use Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store;
use Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory;
use Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

/**
 * Class InstallData
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    const WEBSITE_STORES
        = array(
            'Store One' => 'store_one',
            'Store Two' => 'store_two',
        );

    /**
     * @var WebsiteFactory
     */
    private $websiteFactory;
    /**
     * @var Website
     */
    private $websiteResourceModel;
    /**
     * @var StoreFactory
     */
    private $storeFactory;
    /**
     * @var GroupFactory
     */
    private $groupFactory;
    /**
     * @var Group
     */
    private $groupResourceModel;
    /**
     * @var Store
     */
    private $storeResourceModel;
    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    private $eventManager;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $configResourceModel;

    /**
     * @var State
     */
    private $appState;

    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * InstallData constructor.
     *
     * @param WebsiteFactory   $websiteFactory
     * @param Website          $websiteResourceModel
     * @param Store            $storeResourceModel
     * @param Group            $groupResourceModel
     * @param StoreFactory     $storeFactory
     * @param GroupFactory     $groupFactory
     * @param ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param Config           $configResourcModel
     * @param Logger           $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory,
        Website $websiteResourceModel,
        Store $storeResourceModel,
        Group $groupResourceModel,
        StoreFactory $storeFactory,
        GroupFactory $groupFactory,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        Config $configResourceModel,
        State $appState,
        Logger $logger
    ) {
        $this->websiteFactory       = $websiteFactory;
        $this->websiteResourceModel = $websiteResourceModel;
        $this->storeFactory         = $storeFactory;
        $this->groupFactory         = $groupFactory;
        $this->groupResourceModel   = $groupResourceModel;
        $this->storeResourceModel   = $storeResourceModel;
        $this->eventManager         = $eventManager;
        $this->configResourceModel  = $configResourceModel;
        $this->appState             = $appState;
        $this->logger               = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * Installs data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface   $context
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        try {
            $this->appState->getAreaCode();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $ex) {
            $this->appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
        }

        $setup->startSetup();
        $sortOrder = 0;

        foreach (self::WEBSITE_STORES as $store_name => $store_code) {

            /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\Website $website */
            $website = $this->websiteFactory->create();
            $website->load($store_code);
            if (!$website->getId()) {
                $website->setCode($store_code);
                $website->setName($store_name . ' Website');
                $website->setDefaultGroupId(0);
                $website->setSortOrder(0);
                try {
                    $this->websiteResourceModel->save($website);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->logger->error('fail to save website: ' . $website->getName() . ' ' . $e->getMessage());
                    if (!$website->getId()) {
                       //ignore if website actually did save
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //do not make store/group if website did not save
                continue;
            }
            /** @var  \Magento\Store\Model\Store $store */
            $store = $this->storeFactory->create();
            $store->load($store_code . '_store_view');
            if (!$store->getId()) {
                $store->setCode($store_code . '_store_view');
                $store->setName($store_name . ' Store View');
                $store->setWebsiteId($website->getId());
                $store->setData('is_active', '1');
                $store->setSortOrder($sortOrder);
                try {
                    $this->logger->info('trying to save store');
                    $this->storeResourceModel->save($store);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                    $this->logger->error('fail to save store: ' . $store->getName() . ' ' . $e->getMessage());
                    if (!$store->getId()) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                /* Config */
                $this->configResourceModel
                    ->saveConfig('design/header/logo_width', '173', 'stores', $store->getId())
                    ->saveConfig('design/header/logo_height', '26', 'stores', $store->getId())
                    ->saveConfig('design/theme/theme_id', '4', 'stores', $store->getId())
                    ->saveConfig('design/header/logo_src', 'stores/' . $store->getId() . '/logo.png', 'stores',
                        $store->getId());
                // Trigger event to insert some data to the sales_sequence_meta table (fix bug place order in checkout)
                $this->eventManager->dispatch('store_add', ['store' => $store]);
            }
            if ($website->getId()) {
                /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\Group $group */
                $group = $this->groupFactory->create();
                $group->setWebsiteId($website->getWebsiteId());
                $group->setName($store_name . ' Store');
                $group->setRootCategoryId(2);
                $group->setDefaultStoreId($store->getId());
                $group->setCode($store_code .'_store');
                try {
                    $this->groupResourceModel->save($group);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->logger->error('fail to save group: ' . $group->getName() . ' ' . $e->getMessage());
                    return;
                }
            }

            $website->setDefaultGroupId($group->getId());
            try {
                $this->websiteResourceModel->save($website);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
                if (!$website->getId()) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            $store->setGroupId($group->getId());
            try {
                $this->storeResourceModel->save($store);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                $this->logger->error('cannot save store group ' . $group->getId() . ' ' . $e->getMessage());

                return;
            }
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

fyi - the above code is loosely based on vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-api/Test/_files/websites_with_stores.php

and I think this issue is because because the inventory_stock_x tables that correspond to the website aren't generated yet at this point.

Comment: The issue is in the plugin after website save

vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Plugin/Store/Model/ResourceModel/Website/AssignWebsiteToDefaultStockPlugin.php

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can do it via config.php. You can follow the same structure of the websites created previously.

When you perform the setup:upgrade command it must generate the new website as you want.